# How can I compare regression coefficients from two separate regressions involving the same individuals?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, model-comparison

Here is a toy example for a problem I am having.

I am hypothesizing that:

1. A higher occurrence of repetitive negative thoughts (`repetitive_negative`) will be associated with clinician ratings of depression, holding constant sex and age. And,
2. A higher occurrence obsessive compulsive thoughts (`obsessive`) will not be associated with clinician ratings of depression, holding constant sex and age.
3. Repetitive negative thoughts are a more important predictor of clinician ratings of depression compared to obsessive compulsive thoughts.

I can test hypotheses 1 and 2 through two regressions:

Model 1: `Depression ~ repetitive_negative + age + sex`

Model 2: `Depression ~ obsessive + age + sex`

However, I understand that the difference between a statistically significant regression coefficient and a non-significant regression coefficient, is not itself statistically significant. I need to perform a direct comparison of `repetitive_negative` and `obsessive`. How do I do this? (e.g., in R or SPSS).

Comment: what's preventing you from fitting them in one model? If you want to compare you can compare with linearHypothesis in car https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-7/topics/linearHypothesis or glht

Comment: How do I test all three hypotheses with one model?

Comment: Am I missing something? if you fit Depression ~ repetitive_negative + obsessive + age + sex, you can test your hypothesis? Apologies in advance if i misunderstood the question

Comment: This is probably my ignorance of regression. For hypothesis 1, I want to quantify the relationship between repetitive_negative and depression, holding constant age and sex. However, if I were to include obsessive also in this equation, would this not also hold constant obsessive (which is not what I want?). Isn't this answering a different question to what I'm asking in H1 and H2?